# Share data between 2 React components using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, react.js

In my app I have 3 components:

1. `MovieSearchComponent` to "house" the other 2 components
2. `MovieSearch` to search an API and retrieve the data
3. `MovieResultList` to display the data in the browser

Both components are wrapped in a parent container `MovieSearchComponent`.

My `MovieSearchComponent` looks like this:

```
interface Movie {
  original_title: string;
  id: string;
}

const MovieSearchComponent = () => {
  const [movieList, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);

  const addMovie = ((movies: Movie[]) => {
    setMovies([...movies]);
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MovieSearch addMovie={addMovie} />
      <MovieResultList movieList={movieList}/>      
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

In here I have a empty `MovieList` array that uses the `setMovies` function to fill the `MovieList` array. There's also a `addMovie` function that gets called from the `MovieSearch` component and takes a array as a parameter. Then I pass the `MovieList` array to the `MovieResultList` component.

The `MovieSearch` component:

```
const Search = styled.input`
  color: green;
`

const MovieSearch = ( {addMovie }) => {  
    const apikey = 'api_key=***************dad4';
    const baseurl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?'

    const searchTMDBapi = (e) => {
        e.persist()
        setMovieSearchResults(e);
    }

    const setMovieSearchResults = debounce((e) => {
        const query = e.target.value;
        fetch(baseurl + apikey + '&language=en-US&query=' + query + '&page=1&include_adult=false')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => addMovie(data.results))
  }, 500);

  return <Search placeholder="Search" onChange={searchTMDBapi}/>
}
```

In this function component I render a input field by using styled components. The input field calls the `searchTMDBapi` function when something is typed. In that method I call the `setMovieSearchResults` method which calls the api and sets the api data in the Hook by using `.then(data => addMovie(data.results))`

The `addMovie` Hook updates the `movieList` array in `MovieSearchComponent` and the `<MovieResultList movieList={movieList}/>`  syntax passes the `movieList` array to the `MovieResultList` which renders it:

```
const MovieResultList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {props.movieList.map(movie => {
                    return (<li key={movie.id}>{movie.original_title}</li>)
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My goal was to create 2 components. 1 to retrieve data from a external API and the other to display that data in a different component. I succeeded in that but I was wondering if there are some aspects on which I could improve this code and my React knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MovieSearchComponent

- With the `useState` the common pattern is to name the state update function matching with the state value, i.e. `movieList` and `setMovieList`. This makes it clear what state the function will update.
- I had to read and reread your description of `addMovie` and compare it against the *actual* implementation. It isn't clear if the function is to add *a* movie, add an array of movies, or, based on the implementation, replace existing movie array list. The name of the function and the result of the function executing should match. In your description you say `addMovie` updates the `movielist` array, so for the sake of code review I'll assume that to mean the third option with state *replacement*. In this case the callback function can simply be `setMovieList`. Update the prop name as well.

Code suggestions

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

...

const MovieSearchComponent = () => {
  const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState<Movie[]>([]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MovieSearch setMovieList={setMovieList} />
      <MovieResultList movieList={movieList}/>      
    </Fragment>
  )
};
```

## MovieSearch

- Update prop `addMovie` to `setMovieList`.
- Values like `apiKey` and `baseurl` that *never* change don't need to be in the functional component body and continually redefined. Declare them externally in the file.
- It may be better to extract the synthetic event data and allow the event object to be returned to the event pool as quickly as possible. Extract and pass the event's target's value to `setMovieSearchResults`.
- Handle the `fetch` request's unhappy paths, i.e. a not-successful responses or errors handling successful responses. [Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful).
- You should always standardize and sanitize user input.

Code suggestions

```
const apikey = 'api_key=***************dad4';
const baseurl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?'

const Search = styled.input`
  color: green;
`;

const MovieSearch = ({ setMovieList }) => { 
    const searchTMDBapi = e => {
        const { value } = e.target;

        // Simple example: URI encode and lowercase
        // ... there's more you could do
        const query = encodeURI(value.toLowerCase());

        setMovieSearchResults(query);
    }

    const setMovieSearchResults = debounce(query => {
        fetch(baseurl + apikey + '&language=en-US&query=' + query + '&page=1&include_adult=false')
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => setMovieList(data.results))
          .catch(console.error);
  }, 500);

  return <Search placeholder="Search" onChange={searchTMDBapi}/>
}
```

## MovieResultList

- Pretty simple & clean component. Only suggestion here might be to tighten up variables by using object destructuring.

Code suggestions

```
const MovieResultList = ({ movieList }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {movieList.map(({ id, original_title }) => <li key={id}>{original_title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. Naming "things" in code is harder than actually writing code!

Comment: @PeterBoomsma *"One of the most difficult problems in Computer Science"* :) Welcome.